# Error in running the the 'flutter build apk' command

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-build

I am developing an app using the dart language, flutter framework and firebase as database,  and using the vscode as the code editor. I was running the application in the chrome(debug) and it was working completely fine. But when i tried to build an apk file of the application it is giving me the error:

e: C:/Users/asus/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5201e1a13f9a2d5ba11117fa4f48584e/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

And at last the apk file is build but when i tried to install it in my android device it shows an empty screen.

I tried to solve the problem by referring solutions from the internet. I updated the version of the
Kotlin in the android level file as:
build.gradle file:

[build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SdBI.png)

Also i have updated the gradle-wrapper.properties as:

[gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZWom.png)

Since the application is running properly in the web(chrome) so there will be no problem in the code still uploading the main.dart file:

[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCtEG.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myroY.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3hQD.png)

while running on the web I can see an error that says:
WebGL: this extension has very low support on mobile devices; do not rely on it for rendering effects: WEBGL_polygon_mode

does this somehow related to it?

Comment: Have you tried using kotlin version 1.6.0, as it says in the error?

Comment: Yes i have tried but then it gave that use the latest version of Kotlin. So from the official site i obtained the latest version i.e. 1.9.22. But still the error ocuured.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can try versions like this:

```
//android/build.gradle
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

```
//android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Comment: Yes i have did this but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me once, try to change kotlin version inside the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

PS: do not forget to do: flutter clean and flutter pub get before you re-build apk.

Comment: Did it but still error